# Does strapi support graphql subscriptions?

Tags: graphql, publish-subscribe, strapi

I'm using a headless CMS (strapi) for my backend. My requirement is to send a notification to fe client once a comment is created in the backend.

I need to know whether strapi supports graphql subscriptions (if so can you please share sample code)or is their a better approach to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Strapi does not support this now, but graphql subscriptions are under consideration on the  [strapi roadmap](https://portal.productboard.com/strapi/1-roadmap/c/45-graphql-subscriptions).
Feel free to vote for it to push this topic.

Comment: Link is broken, this is the correct one: https://feedback.strapi.io/developer-experience/p/graphql-subscriptions